# Proving a subsequence converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Lately, I was looking for a proof to show that the subsequence of a sequences converges to the limit but I can't find any formal ones online. And, I was wondering if anyone has a concrete proof or a link for the concrete proof.

Theorem: Any subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent (to the same limit).

Comment: If you look at the definition of convergence carefully, I think that you'll find that this follows immediately once you think about it.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that quite early however what I was looking for was an epsilon proof and I can't seem to find appropriate ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_n \to x$ be a convergent sequence and $(x_{n_j})_{j \geq 1}$ be a convergent subsequence. For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_\epsilon$ implies $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$. Take $j_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_{j_0} \geq n_\epsilon$. So if $j \geq j_\epsilon$, $n_j \geq n_{j_\epsilon} \geq n_\epsilon$, and so $|x_{n_j}-x|<\epsilon$.

---

Take $x_n = 1/n$ for all $n \geq 1$. Then $x_n \to 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_\epsilon$ implies $1/n < \epsilon$. Consider the subsequence $x_{n_j} = 1/2j$, for all $j \geq 1$. I mean $n_j = 2j$. If you take $j_\epsilon$ such that $j_\epsilon \geq n_\epsilon/2$, then $j \geq j_\epsilon$ implies $$2j = n_j \geq n_{j_\epsilon} = 2j_\epsilon  \geq n_\epsilon$$ and so $1/2j < \epsilon$, hence $1/2j \to 0$ too.

Comment: I know it may seem a stretch, but could you possibly provide a short example of this proof?

Comment: Ok. I'll add it as an edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having a little trouble with the terminology. By n subscript 0 are you implying a 0th term of a sequence?

Comment: No. I've changed the notation, see if it helps.

Comment: Does your change infer that all the other zero subscripts change to epsilon too?

Comment: Not necessarily, when I put a zero or an epsilon as a subscript, I mean that I am picking a particular element, and nothing more. But I suppose it's better to be coherent.. (I'll change it too)

Comment: Ok, I see what you have done. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\{x_{p_n}\}$ is a subsequence of the convergent sequence $\{x_n\}$ (with limit L), then for every $\epsilon>0$ choose $N\in\mathbb N$ such that
$$
|x_n-L|<\epsilon
$$
for every $n>N$, now observe that for every $n>N$, we have $p_n>N$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n \to x$. This means that, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N_\varepsilon$ such that, for all $n > N_\varepsilon$, we have $\lvert x_n - x \rvert < \varepsilon$.

Your intuition should be that we can always ensure the tail end of our sequence, $(x_n : n > N_\varepsilon)$, **stays** "sufficiently close" to the limit $x$, no matter how close "sufficiently close" is. This is what the definition of convergence guarantees us.

Now, for a subsequence $(x_{n_k} : k \in \Bbb N)$, we always have $n_k \geq k$, this is a crucial fact.

Can you piece together the rest, to guarantee that we can always find $K_\varepsilon$ so that $\lvert x_{n_k} - x \rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $k > K_\varepsilon$? To put it more bluntly, can you convince yourself that in fact $N_\varepsilon$ works?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence that converges to a limit $x$, $(x_{n_k})$ a subsequence, then for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is some $N$ such that for all $n> N$, $x_n \in U$. Now there is necessarily some $K$ such that for all $k > K$, $n_k > N$, since $n_k$ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers. Then for all $k> K$, $x_{n_k} \in U$. Thus $(x_{n_k})\to x$ as well.